# I can delete users in Active Directory Users and Computers but not in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I've written the following short script to remove stale objects in my Active Directory

```
$csvFilePath = "C:\path\to\file.csv"
Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath | ForEach-Object {
    $username = $_.SamAccountName
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $username
}
```

I can delete user accounts in Active Directory Users and Computers ('ADUC') by right clicking and deleting but not by using the Remove-ADUser cmdlet. I don't understand where I've gone wrong.

I was expecting the script to be remove the users in "C:\path.csv" to be removed from my on-premise Active Directory but I receive the following error:

> Remove-ADUser : Access is denied
> CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (**ACCOUNT I WANT TO DELETE**:ADUser) [Remove-ADUser], UnauthorizedAccessException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : ActiveDirectoryCmdlet:System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.RemoveADUser

I've tried running the script in a standard and elevated terminal. I've also tried running PowerShell with the same privileged user account I can use to delete accounts in using ADUC.

Comment: It's safe to assume you're running PowerShell as the same user that can delete objects in ADUC right? If so, try running PowerShell elevated (run as admin)

Comment: I'm logged into my device using my standard account. When I log on to PowerShell as a different user (i.e. my privileged account) it still shows to be running as my standard account. I can only run with elevated rights using my standard credentials.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of my issue was the fact that I wasn't using PowerShell in the same user context as I am when I can delete accounts from AD Users and Computers **and** when I was, that account couldn't access the directory the script I was pointing at.

When I logged into PowerShell in the correct user context, I modified my script to call the file from C:\ and it worked.

```
$csvFilePath = "C:\file.csv"
Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath | ForEach-Object {
    $username = $_.SamAccountName
    Remove-ADUser -Identity $username
}
```